# It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, debugging

I get this problem very often while debugging a ASP.Net MVC(3) application. I found some workarounds which I post as an answer, but this does not help in all cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This article](http://scottonwriting.net/sowblog/archive/2010/02/17/163375.aspx) explains it well, but the cause in my case was that the Development server sometimes keeps running if you are debugging and abort the program execution.Workarounds: killing the development server manually, restarting Visual Studio, restarting the computer. But sometimes even the last option does NOT work!

Update: I rebuilt the solution prior to hitting the Debug triangle and have not had the problem for a long time now.